# Averageifs using index match to dynamically select the entire column to average

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

how do i use average ifs using index match to return an average with a formula to select the column name? for example, how do i find the average of Column A, if 1or2 is 1? And if I want to average Column B it should calculate B automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(A:F,0,MATCH("B",A1:F1,0)),A:A,1)
```